# Laravel ::all->where returns everything

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I'm trying to get only rows which have column approved filled with value 1

`$reviews = Review::all()->where('approved', '1');
return view('items.show', compact('reviews')`

I also tried

`$reviews = Review::where('approved', '1');
return view('items.show', compact('reviews')`

and then I'm fetching them with

`@foreach ($item->reviews->sortByDesc('created_at') as $review)`

But this return every row from Review table from database no matter what the approved value. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$item->reviews` is not the same object as `$reviews`... That `foreach()` is looping over the wrong thing, should be `foreach($reviews ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is there is no reason to get "all" the records from the database then filter them when you can ask the database to only give you the records you want filtered.

```
$reviews = Review::where('approved', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Second, as mentioned in the comments you should be iterating `$reviews`:

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! The foreach I had was incorrect :)

Answer (score 2):

You must be use

```
$reviews = Review::where('approved', '1')->latest()->get();
return view('items.show', compact('reviews');
```

in blade

```
@foreach ($reviews as $review)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're adding a where condition after the query has executed. In the second you're not executing the query at all.

Instead do `$reviews = Review::where('approved', '1')->get();`